# Cannot Switch my Visibility on a TextView through an OnClick event

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have 2 textviews on my android app with ids : textView1 , textView2 . Among others on my main layout OnClickListener I am trying to make these 2 textViews INVISIBLE with this :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

View activity = findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
activity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        textView2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }});


}
```

I get ... cannot be resolved messages . 
Thank you guyz all in advance for your immediate responses.

Comment: have you initialized textview's 1 and 2. also are they in the same layout inflated?

Comment: What cannot be resolved? The TextViews? Show some more code. How do you define and get them?

Comment: They are in the same layout but I haven't maybe initialized them ... How do I do that ?

Comment: <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/mainmsg"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

Comment: @SymeonLaftsopoulos post the activity code and what is `activity`? a button?

Comment: @SymeonLaftsopoulos do you have view with id `mainlayout` in xml?

Comment: It's ok the code below made it work . Ty all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize textviews

```
TextView textView1,textView2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); 
View activity = (View)findViewById(R.id.mainlayout);
```

Comment: final TextView* else he won't be able to access them in the onClick method

Comment: @Cruceo final not required its declared as a class member

Comment: @Cruceo i edited my post initially it was just the initialization posted no methods then in edited and posted the onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
findViewById(R.id.textView1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
findViewById(R.id.textView2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

`R.id.textView1` & `R.id.textView2` should correspond to the `android:id` fields of the TextViews you want to make invisible in `R.layout.activity_main`

If you're still not getting the expected behavior, make sure you're not confusing [`View.GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) and [`View.INVISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE)